Restrict User in an AD group from logging on to computers but allow them to use their windows credentials to log on to a webapp
I've set up a third-party web application on our IIS server, utilizing Windows authentication. To manage access, I created an AD group for external contractors and included them. These contractors should only log in to the web app, without access to network computers. To enforce this, I configured "logon workstations" for one user in AD, specifying the web server's name. While this successfully restricted access to other computers, it unintentionally hindered authentication for the web app.

What do you mean by "without access to network computers"? Cannot use remote desktop to connect to the machines or something else?

In broad strokes:
Create a Group Policy that assigns the "Deny log on locally" privilege to the security group.
Link the policy at the appropriate level of the domain, and assign it to all computers or specific computers/groups that the computers are a member of. A WMI filter can also be used to distinguish between workstation or server.
